# Generate a sequence and include the last number in r

Tags: r

How do you generate a sequence of numbers and also includes the last number in it?
Check this out to understand what I am saying:
I want to generate the sequence of numbers that run from 0 to 1 with an interval of 0.3.
The formal I know runs like:

```
`seq(0, 1, by=0.3)`
```

The answer to this will be

```
`0,0.3, 0.6, 0.9`
```

However, I want a situation where either of the following is possible:

```
`0,0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1` OR `0, 0.3, 0.6,1`
```

So pretty much in both instances the first and last number are included in the sequence. Is such possible in r?
Thanks.

Comment: You can add in whatever numbers you want with `c()`: `c(seq(0, 1, by=0.3),1)`. But `seq()` itself wont generate numbers out of sequence. You can write your own function to do this for you. Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your customized function:

```
seq(0, 1, by=0.3)

lastnum_seq<-function(w,x,y){
  y<-seq(w,x,by=y)
  return(c(y,x))
}

lastnum_seq(0,1,0.3)
```

Comment: What about `lastnum_seq(0,0.9,0.3)`?

Comment: Out of scope :)