# Create a sequence in r that matches end

Tags: r

I want to create a sequence that completes at the end with "to" value.

for example when I create a seq as in example below, it stops before the end value

```
    > seq(1,13, by = 5)
    [1]  1  6 11
```

I want something like

```
> c(seq(1,13, by = 5), 13)
[1]  1  6 11 13
```

and also something like

```
> c(seq(1,13, by = 5), 18)
[1]  1  6 11 18
```

what are some good ways to do these?

Also I want to do this with dates as well. example below

I have:

```
> seq.Date(from = as.Date("2018-01-01"), to = Sys.Date() , by = "1000 days")
[1] "2018-01-01" "2020-09-27"
```

I want:

```
> c(seq.Date(from = as.Date("2018-01-01"), to = Sys.Date() , by = "1000 days"), Sys.Date())
[1] "2018-01-01" "2020-09-27" "2021-01-12"
```

is it already a good enough way to do it?

Comment: What's wrong with the methods you show already?

Comment: Have you seen these related (duplicate?) questions? [Missing last sequence in seq() in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419281/missing-last-sequence-in-seq-in-r), [Generate a sequence and include the last number in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49263821/generate-a-sequence-and-include-the-last-number-in-r)

Comment: just looking for other options, I am sure there exists elegant ways

Comment: @MauritsEvers, ok I was looking if there is an existing answer but I did not find one :(. May be you help me how did you find a duplicate questions so quickly ?

Comment: Your method seems pretty concise; perhaps wrap it in a custom function. Not sure what more you expect in terms of elegance. I imagine your approach will be hard to beat in terms of code complexity.

Comment: I just googled "seq in R with last value"; the posts I link to were the top two hits. But I agree with you in that it's not always easy to find duplicate/related posts here on SO.